# Why is this implemented binary search so much slower than std::binary_search()?

Tags: c++, performance, binary-search

Before I detected std::upper_bound I implemented my own version of binarySearch to determine the index of a wanted element. The implementation works but in comparision with a linear search my binarySearch is only a little bit faster. The factor between my implementation and the std lib increases as the search area grows.

For a quick selftest I inserted the complete code at the end of this post. For a quick glance here my searchBinary implementation:

```
template<typename T> T searchBinary(const std::vector<std::vector<T> > vectorList, const std::vector<T> compareVector) {
    long iteration = 0;
    size_t leftIndex = 0;
    size_t rightIndex = vectorList.size()-1;
    size_t pos;

    while (leftIndex <= rightIndex) {
        iteration++;
        pos = (leftIndex + rightIndex) / 2;

        if (compareVector < vectorList[pos]) {
            rightIndex = pos - 1;
        } else if (compareVector > vectorList[pos]) {
            leftIndex = pos + 1;
        } else {
            cout << "Match at binary search after " << iteration << " iterations.\n";
            return pos;
        }
    }

    cout << "No match at binary search after " << iteration << " iterations.\n";
    return -1;
}
```

And this is how I messure the runtime:

```
void searchBinaryOwn_messure(std::vector<std::vector<u_char> > vectorList, std::vector<u_char> compareVector) {
    struct timeval begin, end;
    long seconds, useconds;

    if (gettimeofday(&begin,(struct timezone *)0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "can not get time\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    searchBinary(vectorList, compareVector);

    if (gettimeofday(&end,(struct timezone *)0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "can not get time\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    seconds = end.tv_sec - begin.tv_sec;
    useconds = end.tv_usec - begin.tv_usec;
    if(useconds < 0) {
        useconds += 1000000;
        seconds--;
    }

    printf("searchBinaryOwn(): %ld sec %ld usec\n\n", seconds, useconds);
    return;
}
```

Don't see any problems here. If I run ths program with 8 000
 000 elements:

- searchLinear() takes ~3,7sec
- searchBinaryOwn() takes ~2,8sec
- searchBinaryStd() takes ~0,0007sec

**So why is there such a huge difference between the both binary searches?** (compiled with gcc 4.8.2)
Note: because of "cout..."  takes about 30usec, std::binarySearch is in fact way faster than displayed

Here the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;


template<typename T> T searchBinary(const std::vector<std::vector<T> > vectorList, const std::vector<T> compareVector) {
    long iteration = 0;
    size_t leftIndex = 0;
    size_t rightIndex = vectorList.size()-1;
    size_t pos;


    while (leftIndex <= rightIndex) {
        iteration++;
        pos = (leftIndex + rightIndex) / 2;

        if (compareVector < vectorList[pos]) {
            rightIndex = pos - 1;
        } else if (compareVector > vectorList[pos]) {
            leftIndex = pos + 1;
        } else {
            cout << "Match at binary search after " << iteration << " iterations.\n";
            return pos;
        }
    }

    cout << "No match at binary search after " << iteration << " iterations.\n";
    return -1;
}

size_t searchLinear(std::vector<std::vector<u_char> > vectorList, std::vector<u_char> compareVector) {
    size_t vectorListSize = vectorList.size();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vectorListSize; i++) {
        if (vectorList[i] == compareVector) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return (size_t)-1;
}

void searchLinear_messure(std::vector<std::vector<u_char> > vectorList, std::vector<u_char> compareVector) {
    struct timeval begin, end;
    long seconds, useconds;

    if (gettimeofday(&begin,(struct timezone *)0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "can not get time\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //search
    cout << "\nPos: " << searchLinear(vectorList, compareVector) << endl;

    if (gettimeofday(&end,(struct timezone *)0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "can not get time\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    seconds = end.tv_sec - begin.tv_sec;
    useconds = end.tv_usec - begin.tv_usec;
    if(useconds < 0) {
        useconds += 1000000;
        seconds--;
    }

    printf("searchLinear(): %ld sec %ld usec\n\n", seconds, useconds);
    return;
}

void searchBinaryStd_messure(std::vector<std::vector<u_char> > vectorList, std::vector<u_char> compareVector) {
    struct timeval begin, end;
    long seconds, useconds;

    if (gettimeofday(&begin,(struct timezone *)0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "can not get time\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //search
    cout << "found: " << std::binary_search(vectorList.begin(), vectorList.end(), compareVector) << endl;

    if (gettimeofday(&end,(struct timezone *)0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "can not get time\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    seconds = end.tv_sec - begin.tv_sec;
    useconds = end.tv_usec - begin.tv_usec;
    if(useconds < 0) {
        useconds += 1000000;
        seconds--;
    }

    printf("searchBinaryStd(): %ld sec %ld usec\n\n", seconds, useconds);
    return;
}

void searchBinaryOwn_messure(std::vector<std::vector<u_char> > vectorList, std::vector<u_char> compareVector) {
    struct timeval begin, end;
    long seconds, useconds;

    if (gettimeofday(&begin,(struct timezone *)0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "can not get time\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    searchBinary(vectorList, compareVector);

    if (gettimeofday(&end,(struct timezone *)0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "can not get time\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    seconds = end.tv_sec - begin.tv_sec;
    useconds = end.tv_usec - begin.tv_usec;
    if(useconds < 0) {
        useconds += 1000000;
        seconds--;
    }

    printf("searchBinaryOwn(): %ld sec %ld usec\n\n", seconds, useconds);
    return;
}


int main() {
    std::vector<u_char> compareVector;
    compareVector.clear();
    compareVector.push_back(0xF8);
    compareVector.push_back(0xD1);
    compareVector.push_back(0x11);
    compareVector.push_back(0xFF);

    std::vector<std::vector<u_char> > vectorList;
    vectorList.clear();
    std::vector<u_char> temp;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ((unsigned int)-1); i++) {
        if (i == 8000000) {
//      if (i == 15000000) {
            break;
        }
        temp.clear();
        temp.push_back(0x11);
        temp.push_back(0x22);
        temp.push_back(0x33);
        temp.push_back(0x44);
        vectorList.push_back(temp);
    }

    vectorList[7999999] = compareVector;

    cout << "Elements in vectorList: " << vectorList.size() << endl;

    searchLinear_messure(vectorList, compareVector);
    searchBinaryStd_messure(vectorList, compareVector);
    searchBinaryOwn_messure(vectorList, compareVector);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't have time for a closer look, but your `searchBinary`  creates a copy of the both vectors you pass so this will be at least one bottleneck.

Comment: Because MANY people work on the algorithms for a very long time, before they are standardized. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change your function prototypte to

`template<typename T> T searchBinary(const std::vector<std::vector<T> >& vectorList, const std::vector<T>& compareVector) {`

i.e. pass by constant reference not by value. This will avoid two vector copies.

2. You can refactor using a single conditional test `<` per iteration. (You'll also need to change the `while` conditional).
3. Does `iteration` need to be a `long`? Can it not be shorter? What's the worst case for convergence?

Point 1 is the important one. 2 is quite important, 3 is a micro-optimisation that might not make a difference at all on some systems.

Comment: Your item 2 is more than a "micro" optimization.  It is nearly a factor of two.  Unless I misunderstood, you still need the < test on the values being sorted and some conditional test of the indexes in the while.  But getting rid of the > test on values being sorted saves nearly half the time.  Then after the while, you need an extra test to see if leftIndex-1 is the item you were searching for (which is safer and faster if leftIndex were initialized as 1 not 0).  If the printed number of iterations were actually interesting, this whole idea fails.  But I'll assume it was not.

Comment: You're correct of course. I've sharpened up my language. If you were to supply the code in your answer I'd certainly upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

The vectors are passed to `searchBinary` by value, hence copies will be created which takes time.

If you change the signature to

```
template<typename T> T searchBinary(const std::vector<std::vector<T> >& vectorList, const std::vector<T>& compareVector)
```

it is as fast as the std implementation: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/qozapTfn3MrGv5JA

Answer (score 0):

Well this `template<typename T> T searchBinary(const std::vector<std::vector<T> > vectorList, const std::vector<T> compareVector)` makes a copy of input vector (as you pass it by value), which is linear in time. So the result you get is actually expected.

Btw. a tounge-in-cheek answer could be that standard library is written by quite good developers, it is expected to be hardly outperformed.